# Invalid Profile Issue in iPad

Tags: iphone, macos, ipad, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I tried to install a provisioning profile by sending it as a mail attachment. When I tried to open it there is an error message comming up saying 'Invalid Profile'. But when I double click the same profile in my MAC it added to Xcode without any problem. When I go and see organizer it says valid profile. Can some one please help me to solve this problem

Comment: There are many reasons why this could fail. Did you make sure that the UDID is the iPas is in the profile? Also when you build an AdHoc version the profile will be embedded in the IPA and there is not need to provide the provisioning profile separated.

Comment: I have used distribution certificate to build the provisioning profile and it also not a AdHoc one but Inhouse application. Also my initial problem is not installing the ipa file in the iPad. At the end i figured out that the problem is with the provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

No need to install provisioning profile into device. Though you can install it, but it will install automatically when IPA get installed. 
The error you getting, shows that the provisioning profile, you trying to install, does not include your device UUID. In xcode, it shows valid profile because xcode will check only for certificates and private key associated with that profile. Xcode will not check for which devices are included with proviosioning profile.

Comment: my initial problem is not installing the ipa file in the iPad. At the end i figured out that the problem is with the provisioning profile. I am using the Inhouse Distribution certificate to build the provisioning profile. According to my knowledge I don't need to add UUID to the profile